# IDEA показывает полный путь пакетов

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij Начал показывать полный путь всех пакетов, что немного раздражает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отметите правильный ответ ?

Comment: Это не баг, это фича (с). В Java имя пакета - это части его пути, соединенные точкой. Наоборот - неудобно, когда нужно пройти через несколько уровней вложенности, прежде чем доберешься до нужного java файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снимите эту галочку и все будет окей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]